# Can I launch Android emulator on the same window as VSCode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I use Android emulator with VSCode and I want to control both the emulator and the VSCode window as one window.

Current state:

[image]

I want it to behave as one window. It could look something like this:

[image]

And when I change the size or focus of the window it will affect both apps.

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Thanks!

Comment: Different apps, different windows. You probably should look at window tile / tiling features in you OS / desktop shell.

Comment: Android Emulator is using as low level graphics of the OS to draw in the window, closer to games than a PC CRUD app, As VSCode is based on the Blink (Chromium) engine and you can look at [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) to see how difficult it would be to integrate. You don't mention what OS you are running, you might find a power user solution by asking in the appropriate forum.